# Extract multiple numbers from a string after a specific substring

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, text-extraction

I have the following string:

```php
H: 290​‐​314 P: 280​‐​301+330​​​​U+200B+331​string‐​305+351+338​‐​308+310 [2]
```

I need all the numbers after `P:`: `[280,301,330,331,305,351,338,308,310]`.

Note that there is this `U+200B` which is a char-code and should be ignored.

I tried `#P:\s((\d+)[​\‐]+)+#` but that doesn't work.

Comment: Also, FYI, you can watch [my "`\G` operator uses cases" YT video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dsGUbvW5hsE) to get better acquainted with this anchor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```php
(?:\G(?!\A)(?:[^\d\s]*200B)?|P:\h*)[^\d\s]*\K(?!200B)\d+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IHAaT2/1/).

*Details*:

- `(?:\G(?!\A)(?:[^\d\s]*200B)?|P:\h*)` - either the end of the previous successful match and then any zero or more chars other than digits/whitespace and `200B`, or `P:` and zero or more horizontal whitespaces
- `[^\d\s]*` - zero or more chars other than digits and whitespace
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards the text matched so far from the overall match memory buffer
- `(?!200B)\d+` - one or more digits that are not starting the `200B` char sequence.

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/mib8W):

```php
$text = 'H: 290‐314 P: 280‐301+330U+200B+331string‐305+351+338‐308+310 [2]';
if (preg_match_all('~(?:\G(?!\A)(?:[^\d\s]*200B)?|P:\h*)[^\d\s]*\K(?!200B)\d+~', $text, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[0]);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 280
    [1] => 301
    [2] => 330
    [3] => 331
    [4] => 305
    [5] => 351
    [6] => 338
    [7] => 308
    [8] => 310
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the continue operator this way: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/BcPRd))

```
$str = 'H: 290‐314 P: 280‐301+330U+200B+331string‐305+351+338‐308+310 [2]';
preg_match_all('~(?:P: |\G(?!^)(?:U\+200B)?[^\d ]+)\K\d+~', $str, $m);
var_export($m[0]);
```

Start from `P:`  then match consecutive digits.
Consume non-digit, non-spaces, and your blacklisted string as delimiters.
Forget unwanted substrings with `\K`.